# C# LINQ to select element from string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have a string:

```
private const string Codes = "2,10";

public void method()
{
    var displayCodes = Codes.Split(',');
    DemoResponse response = webService.GetResponse();  //getting response from API

    if(response.Errors.Any(x => displayCodes.Contains(x.StackTrace))
    {
         int myCode = int.Parse(response.Errors.Select(x => x.StackTrace).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

This is the "DemoResponse" model:

```
public class DemoResponse
{
     public bool Validate { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ErrorResponse> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorResponse
{
     public string Message { get; set; }
     public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

The DemoResponse "response" from the API returns result as: (for example)

```
 { 
    "Validate" : false,
    "Errors" : 
             {
                "Message" : "test1",
                "StackTrace" : "2"
             }
  }
  { 
     "Validate" : false,
     "Errors" : 
             {
                "Message" : "test1",
                "StackTrace" : "2"
             }
  }
  { 
     "Validate" : false,
     "Errors" : 
             {
                "Message" : "test1",
                "StackTrace" : "95"
             }
  }
```

The DemoResponse "response" will always contain only one of the code from const string "Codes", i.e either 2 or 10. But may contain other codes.

If the DemoResponse "response" contains the code 2 as the first Code, then this line works fine:

```
int myCode = int.Parse(response.Errors.Select(x => x.StackTrace).FirstOrDefault());
```

But if the DemoResponse "response" does not have code 2 as first, then how do I write a LINQ to select Code 2 and assign to "myCode" variable?
For example:

```
  "StackTrace" : "95",
  "StackTrace" : "95",
  "StackTrace" : "2"
```

Comment: You need to use `Where` method and invert parse code to handle no "2" at all. `int myCode = response.Errors.Where(e => e.StackTrace == "2").Select(e => int.Parse(e.StackTrace)).FirstOrDefault();` - for either possible code, do `int myCode = response.Errors.Where(e => displayCodes.Contains(e.StackTrace)).Select(e => int.Parse(e.StackTrace)).FirstOrDefault();` Note: You don't need your `if`, `myCode` will be `0` if neither code is present.

Answer (score -1):

Need to add for each loop inside if condition.

```
private const string Codes = "2,10";

public void method()
{
    var displayCodes = Codes.Split(',');
    DemoResponse response = webService.GetResponse();  //getting response from API

    if(response.Errors.Any(x => displayCodes.Contains(x.StackTrace))
    {
        foreach (ErrorResponse item in response.Errors)
        {
          // write your logic based on your requirement

          if(int.Parse(item.StackTrace) == 2)
          {
          int myCode = int.Parse(item.StackTrace);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can only set one value to "myCode" variable.
I tried this - 

              



                 `int myCode = int.Parse(response.Errors
                        .Where(x => displayCodes.Contains(x.StackTrace)).Select(x => x.StackTrace).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: As per your question, required StackTrace=2 value as 1st priority to assign into mycode variable right? there is multiple possibilities as per you like 2,95,95  or 95,95,2  or 95,2,95. So for 1st working fine in your code.  now for the 2nd and 3rd scenarios, you can go with foreach and in addition conditions like if StackTrace=2 then assign to mycode else not.   check updated answer for same

Comment: LINQ can handle this very easily, a `foreach` loop is overkill.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that what you *want* to receive form the API is an array of information, but in your code you are mapping what you receive from the API into a single object of type `DemoResponse`. I suspect that you actually want `response` to be a **list or array of `DemoResponse`s**.

Furthermore, from my understanding of the following question:

> But if the DemoResponse "response" does not have code 2 as first, then how do I write a LINQ to select Code 2 and assign to "myCode" variable?

, you want to assign the first `StackTrace` value that *matches any of the codes in `Codes`*, to `myCode`; rather than assigning *any* `StackTrace` value to `myCode`.

If those two assumptions are correct, you could try the following:

```
private const string Codes = "2,10";

public void method()
{
    var displayCodes = Codes.Split(',');

    // NOTE: response is now an array of DemoResponse; 
    // GetResponse()'s implementation and return type may need to be rewritten accordingly
    DemoResponse[] response = webService.GetResponse();

    var errors = response.SelectMany(r => r.Errors);
    
    if (errors.Any(x => displayCodes.Contains(x.StackTrace)))
    {
        int myCode = int.Parse(errors.Select(x => x.StackTrace).First(s => displayCodes.Contains(s)));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could look loop through the stack traces rather than the errors:

```
var stackTraces = response.SelectMany(r => r.Errors).Select(e => e.StackTrace);
    
if (stackTraces.Any(s => displayCodes.Contains(s)))
{
    int myCode = int.Parse(stackTraces.First(s => displayCodes.Contains(s)));
}
```